# Angular CLI doesn't include all packages on ng build --prod

Tags: angular, angular-cli, mqtt, angular7, production-environment

I'm done Angular 7 Project and when i load on server debug version ( `ng build` ), everythings works. 
But in production ( `ng build --prod`) the mqtt included doesn't works.

So i used https://www.npmjs.com/package/paho-mqtt this plugin.

And when i run `ng build` normally, and i load the dist, works on server. But if i use `ng build --prod` the paho mqtt doesn't works, on the same server. Works only in `ng build`
Why ?

Sorry but i'm newer of Angular and i didn't understand why don't works.

Comment: Did you maybe install it and forget to add --save, or save it as a dev dependency (--save-dev)?

Comment: @N15M0_jk let me try, re-install and i let you know

Comment: @N15M0_jk not works...i've re-installed but not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you got it working.

Basically:

1) Delete your `node_modules` folder

2) Make sure you installed and saved it
`npm i paho-mqtt --save`

This will ensure the package wasnt cached incorrectly and install it as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for builds to work in production, a command such as `npm run build` is used which creates a build folder with all the files needed to run the app.